# Documentation of /sys/block/*/device/type

Tags: linux, kernel, sysfs

Where is documentation of `/sys/block/*/device/type` ?
I need information about this file .

```
cat /sys/block/*/device/type
0 
0
5
```

what is this numbers meaning ?

Answer (score 1):

This `type` entry exports [the `type` field in the `scsi_device`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/include/scsi/scsi_device.h#L138) structure (using [this setup](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.7.4/source/drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c#L668)), and shows [the SCSI peripheral device type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Peripheral_Device_Type). 0 corresponds to direct-access block devices, 5 to CD/DVD-ROM drives.